# SSRS Passing Parameters in an Action Expression based on contents of grid/cell

Tags: reporting-services, action, drilldown, ssrs-expression

In my main table, I have a fairly complex query pulling 2 kinds of data and displaying them in one grid. Currently, if the user clicks on a value, they will be able to drill down into a breakdown of the data they clicked on. The problem is that I can only display data for one of the types of data.

I would like to display a breakdown of the other type but it would require displaying on a different report using similar parameters. I am looking for a way to pass parameters to sub-reports based on the contents of what I am clicking. For example (In the action expression) I have tried this:

```
=IIf(Fields!Type.Value = "Job", "/Production Planning/SupportReports/Job_Plan_Board_Job_BD_v1 & Parameters!ReqByDate.Value", "/Production Planning/SupportReports/Job_Plan_Board_Plan_BD_v1 & , Parameters!ReqByDate2.Value")
```

The parameter values are not passing. - I am pretty sure it is syntax as I have already tried everything I could think of with the parameter expressions...

Comment: If it is coming from same data set (query), you probably don't need subreport. Can you show your result set from dataset and show a mockup of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I found my answer in the expression buttons used to turn the parameter on or off in the action. I turned the parameter I needed for one report 'off' and the others 'on' based on the information.  -  I didn't notice the ability to do that before I asked the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your fields are correct, you just need to fix your syntax. You parameters need to be outside of the quotes so the value can be appended to the string.

```
=IIf(Fields!Type.Value = "Job", 
"/Production Planning/SupportReports/Job_Plan_Board_Job_BD_v1" & Parameters!ReqByDate.Value, 
"/Production Planning/SupportReports/Job_Plan_Board_Plan_BD_v1" & Parameters!ReqByDate2.Value)
```

If the Type = Job and the ReqDate is 09152015 then the subreport name (? - not sure what) would be **/Production Planning/SupportReports/Job_Plan_Board_Job_BD_v109152015**.

Now that I think of it, you could shorten this a little bit:

```
="/Production Planning/SupportReports/Job_Plan_Board" &  
 IIf(Fields!Type.Value = "Job", 
 "Job_BD_v1" & Parameters!ReqByDate.Value, 
 "Plan_BD_v1" & Parameters!ReqByDate2.Value)
```